# c# foreach Dynamically generated HTML table

Tags: c#, foreach, tr

```
@{ int count = 0;}
@if (Model != null)
{
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">                        
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
       @if (count == 0)
       {
           <tr>
       }
       <td style="width:25%">
           <table>
               <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Title)</td></tr>
               <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Content)</td></tr>
               <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Author)</td></tr>
           </table>
       </td>

       @if (count == 3)
       {
           </tr>
       }

       @if (count == 3)
       { count = 0; }
       else (count != 3)
       { count++; }
    }
    </table>
}
```

As the title says,

I tried to use FOREACH to dynamically generate tables in HTML.

But a problem has occurred.

My logic is to dynamically generate a 4*N Table.

But the code on the red box is recognized as text by the program.

Causes the program in the red box to not work.

How can I fix it?

---

Added @ after the occurrence

He detected that there is no end

Causes the following to become text

Finally jump out does not exist }

Comment: Did you try putting the @ symbol in front of the if statement? i.e. 

@if(count ==3)

Comment: You should edit your question and post your code there, not in an image

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stackoverflow!
Please post your code here and not on any other outside source.
For your problem - you are missing a space after the if(count) -> if (count)

Comment: @wazdev 
I added the if before @ but it caused the outermost if (Model != null) not found}

Answer (score 0):

OK, this seemed able to compile when I put the output of the If conditions to Html.Raw :

```
@{ int count = 0;}
@if (Model != null)
{
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">                        
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (count == 0)
        {
            @Html.Raw("<tr>")
        }

        <td style="width:25%">
           <table>
               <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Title)</td></tr>
               <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Content)</td></tr>
               <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Author)</td></tr>
           </table>
       </td>

       if (count == 3)
       {
           @Html.Raw("</tr>")
       }

       if (count == 3)
       { count = 0; }
       else if (count != 3)
       { count++; }
    }
</table>}
```

Comment: I added the if before @ but it caused the outermost if (Model != null) not found}The code I modified has been updated to the above.Or is my position wrong?

Comment: I redid the answer quite a bit.  Check it out and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you ~ It can work successfully。I also found another way  use  @:<tr> have the same effect

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for solving the problem.

The revised program is as follows

@{ int count = 0;}

```
@if(Model != null)
{
    <table style="width:100%" border="1">                        
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if(count == 0)
        {                                
            @:<tr>
        }
        <td style="width:25%">
            <table>
                <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Title)</td></tr>
                <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Content)</td></tr>
                <tr><td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Item_Author)</td></tr>
            </table>
        </td>
        if(count == 3)
        {
            @:</tr>
        }

        if(count == 3)
        { count = 0; }
        else
        { count++; }
    }
    </table>
}
</td>
```